# Specialise functor when template class is_convertible to a well known type

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++-concepts, c++17

So I want to apply specific code when a template type `boost::is_convertible` to `WellKnownType`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        // apply specific function to m_t
        // if T is convertible to WellKnownType
    }
    T m_t;
};
```

For this, I thought on using a functor:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_functor {
    void operator()(T& t) {
        // do nothing by default
    }
};
```

Then, I would like to specialise this functor to do something else when `boost::is_convertible<T, WellKnownType>`:

```
template <>
struct my_functor<...> {
    void operator()(T& t) {
        // do something to t because it is convertible to WellKnownType 
    }
};
```

Then, I guess I can easily change `Foo` definition to use the functor and do something when `T` is convertible to `WellKnownType` and do nothing when it is not:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        my_functor<T>()(m_t);
    }
    T m_t;
};
```

What I don't know is how to achieve this behaviour. I know about `BOOST_CONCEPT_REQUIRES`, but can't figure out how to apply it to a template specialisation. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like following with your functor

```
template<typename T, typename WellKnownType >
struct my_functor
{
    void operator()( const T& x) { 
       myopImpl(x, boost::is_convertible<T, WellKnownType>() ); 
    }

    void  myopImpl(T const& x, boost::false_type) 
    {  std::cout << "Some Other Stuff \n";  }

    void  myopImpl(T const& x, boost::true_type)  
    { std:: cout << "Some Specific Stuff \n";  }

};
```

[*`Demo here`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10843b64b83415ba)

Comment: That will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this C++11, you should use the standard library type traits instead of the Boost ones. Also, you can partially specialize on a type trait - it just has to be another template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename WellKnownType, typename = void>
struct my_functor
{
    void operator()(T const& x) { 
        // generic code  
    }
};

template <typename T, typename WellKnownType>
struct my_functor<T, WellKnownType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T, WellKnownType>::value>
    >
{
    void operator()(T const& x) {
        // specific code if convertible
    }
};
```

If you don't like the look of the 3rd argument, you can put that in a namespace and then simply add:

```
template <typename T, typename WellKnownType>
using my_functor = details::my_functor<T, WellKnownType>;
```

Alternatively, you can use the type trait to alias to one of two entirely unrelated functor types:

```
template <typename T, typename WellKnownType>
using my_functor = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_convertible<T, WellKnownType>::value,
    my_functor_specific<T>,
    my_functor_generic<T>>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for completeness, making some research I ended up with also this option using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of`:

```
template <typename T>
void do_it( typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<WellKnownType, T>::value, T>::type& t )
{
    std::cout << "Specific code\n";
}

...

template <typename T>
void do_it( typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<WellKnownType, T>::value, T>::type& t )
{
    std::cout << "Generic code\n";
}
```

Comment: If you had actually tried this, you'll notices that it doesn't work. `T` is in a non-deduced context.

Comment: I tried it as free functions and it does, I'll change the code just to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, if you explicitly specify the type, which is sort of OK if it's a normal function, but rather ridiculous with `operator()`.